# Filter stories based on status but include all their subtasks

Tags: jira, jql

I want to select all Stories which are not in the status "Backlog".
Those should be selected and for all of them I want to get the complete list of all subtasks they have.

```
project = "Android Appli" AND issuetype in (Story, Sub-task) AND status != Backlog
```

Would can't handle to say something like Story.status != Backlog

On my thouhgts was to do something like a combined selection
issuetype in (Story, Sub-task) FROM (project = "Android Appli" AND issuetype = Story AND status != Backlog)

Answer (score 2):

Probably this is not possible with out-of-the-box JQL functions in Jira.

You may need to have an extension (add-on/app) installed on the Jira, like ScriptRunner or JQL Tricks.

Try something like this:

```
project = "Android Appli" AND (
    issuetype = Story AND status != Backlog OR
    issueFunction in subtasksOf("issuetype = Story AND status != Backlog")
)
```

Please note that `issueFunction` is special field related to paid *[ScriptRunner](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/6820/scriptrunner-for-jira?hosting=server&tab=overview)* add-on.

You might have *[JQL Tricks](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/31399/jql-tricks-plugin?hosting=server&tab=overview)* installed instead.

See also more information in my related answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57898057/1572749