# Filtering Jira API call based on Userstory not having subtask

Tags: postman, jira

Situation :
I want to create subtask for stories only if they dont have subtask

Status :
I am able to loop and create subtask for stories now based on jql query

Question :
How do i filter only userstories that have subtasks: [0] ?

Our Jira doesnt have the JQL function to filter on story without subtask so trying through the API or javascript

Answer (score 0):

By default, you cannot do this search in common Jira. However, modern and well-maintained Jira instances usually have advanced searching add-ons installed:

- [**ScriptRunner**](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/6820/scriptrunner-for-jira?hosting=server&tab=support) (check its [JQL functions](https://docs.adaptavist.com/sr4js/6.27.0/features/jql-functions/included-jql-functions), e.g. `issueFunction in hasSubtasks()`)
- [**JQL Tricks**](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/31399/jql-tricks-plugin?hosting=server&tab=support) (check its [JQL functions](https://www.j-tricks.com/jqlt-dc-usage.html), e.g. `issue in hasSubtasks()`)

See also my [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66983393/filter-stories-based-on-status-but-include-all-their-subtasks/67197019#67197019).

**Note:** It also depends on whether you use on-premise Jira (Server/DC) or Cloud one.